# Using extends in itemtype in Hybris

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

What happens if I do not specify extends in itemtype in Hybris when I create a new itemtype?

Eg:

```
<itemtype code="Unit
              jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.product.Unit"
              autocreate="true"
              generate="true">
        <deployment table="Units" typecode="10"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. 
It extends by default to GenericItem.
So the above code will automatically be converted to:

```
<itemtype code="PaymentInfo"
              extends="GenericItem"
              jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.order.payment.PaymentInfo"
              autocreate="true"
              generate="true">
```

Comment: Keep in mind to specify a deployment table. Or all your items will go to generic items table requiring hybris to filter this database for the itemtype. Huge performance leak.

Comment: Just saw that you have the deployment table in your question.

Comment: Can you please suggest some websites for Hybris tutorials? @JohannesNolte

Comment: https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD/SHIP/en-US or https://hybrismart.com/ or https://www.helphybris.com/

Comment: Happy to help!!